# Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 3.0.5 results in Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=3.4.0.0

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I upgraded Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions to version 3.0.5 and Microsoft.CodeAnalysis cannot be loaded anymore. I downgraded to version 3.0.3 and it works fine there.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug indeed : https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/397

Answer (score 1):

I updated my all fun app projects to 3.0.5 from 3.0.3. They built just fine and executed fine too. I noticed `microsoft.codeanalysis.common` has version 3.3.0. I explicitly installed `Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis -Version 3.4.0` and everything still works just fine.

May be you can explicitly install package with `Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis -Version 3.4.0` and try? You can also find out which package is dependent on Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=3.4.0.0

Comment: Hi @Raj strange I am using version 3.4.0. I also tried to install the package explicitly but without luck. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @doorman To be honest, I haven't faced any problems. Recently, people often encounter problems with 3.0.4 and 3.0.5, but 3.0.3 is no problem. I'm curious what exactly happened, because it is no problem on my side,. if there are any updates please let me know, thanks very much.:)

Comment: Hi @Raj try doing a clean / Rebuild of the project, I faced issue once I rebuilt, before that didn't face any issues